# Constraints are breaking in iPad with null values

Tags: ios

I am making an universal app. I am adding table footer view. And I am using a filler view in between last table cell and table footer view.The height of filler view is dynamically set.
Its working fine in iPhone.But when I run the same on iPad its working but I am getting log warnings of breaking constraints.
And I am not getting what type and where my constraints are breaking.
Below is the log warning:-

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
```

> (
>       "(null), First View: 0x78f0c0f0: (null), Second View: 0x78f37240: (null)",
>       "(null), First View: 0x78f15550: (null), Second View: 0x78f0c0f0: (null)",
>       "(null), First View: 0x788d2c50: (null), Second View: 0x78f15550: (null)",
>       "(null), First View: 0x78fe3720: (null), Second View: 0x788d2c50: (null)",
>       "(null), First View: 0x78f37240: (null), Second View: 0x78fe3720: (null)",
>       "(null), First View: 0x788d2c50: (null), ",
>       "(null), First View: 0x78f0c0f0: (null), ",
>       "(null), First View: 0x78f37240: (null), " )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
(null), First View: 0x78f0c0f0: (null),

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Help is really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I tried by putting symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints.But its not catching it.

Comment: Did you changed the directory of your project? If yes than sometimes Xcode change the `wAny` and `hAny` of controllers. So try to set `wAny` and `hAny` as you have chosen while creating the controllers.

Comment: Yes Vijay, I checked this thing at very first place.Its wAny and hAny.I also checked in wRegular and hRegular for iPad.

Answer (score 0):

change wAny hAny to wRegular hRegular and Check preview by select view and go to  Show the Assistant Editor -> change manual to Preview and check the changes required